# ffmpeg mpd restream CPU load gets higher over time

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have a problem with mpd while restreaming it, the CPU load becomes higher after each hour. Is there any solution for it?

I am using ffmpeg Version 5.

Here is the command I've ran :

`ffmpeg -re -i https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/live/live-low-latency.isml/.mpd -c:v copy -c:a copy -sn -shortest -strict -2 -max_muxing_queue_size 400`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i mean this mpd demo test is live when i restream it , cpu pid ffmpeg start 2.0 % after 1 hour be 4.0 % and each hour became higher for exmple 13 hours uptime stream became pid ffmpeg cpu 80 %, and there just copy to copy not transcoder that is strange only mpd protocol, i hope you understood what i mean !